# Sort rows in pandas based on type of string value

Tags: pandas

I have a list of mobile sensor data that I am experimenting with, I searched around a lot but for some reason I can't get it to work. The datasheet (xlsx file) has the following setup:

```
Type              From                 Till         Value 
LightSensor  12/12/2018 22:27:06  12/12/2018 22:27:06  3 
LightSensor  12/12/2018 22:27:08  12/12/2018 22:27:08  3 
LockScreen  12/12/2018 22:27:10  12/12/2018 22:27:10  LOCK
```

Now I want to get all the rows that contain the value 'LightSensor'. But I struggle to get only those values (I want to plot/analyse that later). I was thinking about making a for loop and then match with == 'LightSensor', but then I get the 'truth value error' What would be an efficient solution to get all values to use them for work after that?

Comment: Maybe try `data[data['Type] == 'LightSensor']`. Also what do you mean by the "truth value error"? Please be more explicit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `loc` function!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('some_file.xlsx')

df = df.loc[df.Type == 'LightSensor']
```

This is assuming your Excel sheet has the format exhibited in the question...

Comment: Great thanks, I've been messing around with this for quite a while and can't figure out how to do this. From the sheet I want to plot a graph that contains the amount of people that have the available sensors activated in format Date/AmountOfUsers/SensorType. For example:
15/02/2019 25 Lightsensor
15/02/2019 30 Stepcounter
I want to plot this, I've tried countless of things and go from error to error. Any suggestions?